# Can't find KafkaTemplate bean, even though I've defined one

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, autowired

My environment context looks like this:

```
- Spring Boot v2.5.12
- Maven Multi Module project (this is a module, it imports its Spring Boot dependencies from the parent pom)
- JDK 11
```

And the error that I am receiving looks like this:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.example.group.service.SomeServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' in your configuration.
```

The relevant files:

```xml
<!-- ${base.dir}/pom.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>master-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>app1</module>
        <module>app2</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
        <spring.boot.version>2.5.12</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Omitted -->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>

<!-- ${base.dir}/app2/pom.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app2</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

```java
// ${base.dir}/app2/src/main/java/com/example/group/SomeApplication.java

package com.example.group;

/* Imports omitted */

@SpringBootApplication
public class SomeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class, args);
    }
}

// ${base.dir}/app2/src/main/java/com/example/group/configuration/AppConfig.java
package com.example.group.configuration;

/* Imports omitted */

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Bytes, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Bytes, Object> kafkaProducerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(kafkaProducerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Bytes, Object> kafkaProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProperties = /* Config omitted */;
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProperties);
    }
}

// ${base.dir}/app2/src/main/java/com/example/group/service/SomeService.java
package com.example.group.service;

/* Imports omitted */

@Service
public final class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeServiceImpl.class);

    private final KafkaTemplate<Bytes, Object> kafkaTemplate;
    private final String topic;

    @Autowired
    public SomeServiceImpl(
        KafkaTemplate<Bytes, Object> kafkaTemplate,
        @Value("${topic}") String topic) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    /* omitted */
}
```

This is bizarre and I cannot figure out why Spring keeps telling me it cannot find a `KafkaTemplate` bean. Even IntelliJ tells me that it cannot find an autowire candidate for `KafkaTemplate`.

### Things I've tried

1. Deleting my custom `@Bean`s, and relying on `KafkaAutoConfiguration` (it fails, saying it cannot find a `ProducerFactory`)
2. Giving the `KafkaTemplate` bean a name, and using `@Qualifier` in `SomeService`
3. Moving the `@Bean` definitions around.

None of these have worked, and so I'm at my wits end. Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: Add @EnableKafka to your Spring Boot Application java file and try

Comment: Try declare that bean as `KafkaTemplate<?, ?>` type - not with those specific generics.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I managed to find the issue. It was a case of PEBKAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this was a case of PEBKAC (Problem exists between keyboard and chair).

The `Bytes` type in my config object referred to `com.google.common.primitives.Bytes` and the `Bytes` in my service class referred to `org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes`.

Lesson to self:

Check your types.

Comment: That's not fair! We cannot see that from your question :smile: